# Interpreting multinomial logistic regression in scikit-learn

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, multinomial-distribution, scikit-learn

I am running a multinomial logistic regression for a classification problem involving 6 classes and four features.

Here is the code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split    

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.20)

logreg = LogisticRegression(multi_class = 'multinomial', solver = 'newton-cg')
logreg = logreg.fit(X_train, Y_train)
output2 = logreg.predict(X_test)

logreg.intercept_
logreg.coef_
logreg.classes_
```

And I get the following output:

Intercept

```
array([-1.33803785, -1.55807614, -1.63809549, -0.05199907,  3.72777888, 0.85842968])
```

Coefficients

```
array([[  3.59830486,   5.1370334 ,   1.32336325,   4.89734568],
       [  3.5507364 ,   5.2459697 ,   1.48523684,   4.81653704],
       [  3.35193267,   5.40124363,   2.04869296,   3.885547  ],
       [ -5.4930705 ,   5.49483357,   1.96479926,  -6.7624365 ],
       [ -8.61513183,  -3.77761893,  -7.79363153, -11.72171457],
       [  3.6072284 , -17.50146139,   0.97153921,   4.88472135]])
```

Classes

```
array([u'Dropper', u'Flat', u'Grower', u'New User', u'Non User', u'Stopper'], dtype=object)
```

I am not able to interpret the models. As I understand multinomial logistic regression, for K possible outcomes, running K-1 independent binary logistic regression models, in which one outcome is chosen as a "pivot" and then the other K-1 outcomes are separately regressed against the pivot outcome.

As per this, there must be 5 equations for the 6 classes. But here there are 6. How come?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

As the probabilities of each class must sum to one, we can either define `n-1` independent coefficients vectors, or `n` coefficients vectors that are linked by the equation `\sum_c p(y=c) = 1`.

The two parametrization are equivalent.
See also in Wikipedia [Multinomial logistic regression - As a log-linear model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression#As_a_log-linear_model).

For a class `c`, we have a probability `P(y=c) = e^{b_c.X} / Z`, with `Z` a normalization that accounts for the equation `\sum_c P(y=c) = 1`.
These probabilities are the expected probabilities of a class given the coefficients. They can be computed with `predict_proba`

---

To have better insight of the coefficients, please consider the left plot in [this example](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_logistic_multinomial.html).
[example http://scikit-learn.org/dev/_images/plot_logistic_multinomial_001.png](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_logistic_multinomial.html)

In this example there are 3 classes a, b, c and 2 features `x0`, `x1`. The class is noted `y`.

After the fit of a multinomial logistic, each class as a coefficients vector `C` with 2 components (for the 2 features): `(C_a0, C_a1)`, `(C_b0, C_b1)`, `(C_c0, C_c1)`
There is also an intercept (aka biais) `I` for each class, which are always unidimensional: `I_a`, `I_b`, `I_c`

**The dash line represents the hyperplane defined by `C` and `I`:**
example: for class a, the hyperplane is defined by the equation `x0 * C_a0 + x1 * C_a1 + I_a = 0`
This is the hyperplane where `P(y=a) = e^{x0 * C_a0 + x1 * C_a1 + I_a} / Z = 1 / Z`.
If `C_a0` is positive, when `x0` increases `P(y=a)` increases.
If `C_a0` is negative, when `x0` increases `P(y=a)` decreases.

**However this is not the decision boundary.**
The decision boundary between classes a and b is defined by the equation:
`p(y=a) = p(y=b)` which is `e^{x0 * C_a0 + x1 * C_a1 + I_a} = e^{x0 * C_b0 + x1 * C_b1 + I_b}`
or again `x0 * C_a0 + x1 * C_a1 + I_a = x0 * C_b0 + x1 * C_b1 + I_b`.
This boundary hyperplane is visible in the plot by the background colors.
If `C_a0 - C_b0` is positive, when `x0` increases `P(y=a) / P(y=b)` increases.
If `C_a0 - C_b0` is negative, when `x0` increases `P(y=a) / P(y=b)` decreases.

Comment: Is the choice of `n-1` coefficients important? I mean does it matter which class is omitted from the coefficient estimations part?

Comment: no it does not matter

Answer (score 2):

Let W = array of coefficients(6x4 matrix) , b = intercepts, then

y = W*X + $b^T$ gives a 6x1 vector of probabilities corresponding to each class, of which the class having highest probability is your prediction.

Note: X can be a 4xm vector of features, where 'm' is the number of inputs. In that case y is a 6xm vector, where each column gives the prediction corresponding to each of the 'm' inputs.

Comment: I took one sample point and computed y. It is giving the following: array([ 114.43147212,  116.6419323 ,  120.22216222,   74.84099834, -150.42351551, -275.7130496 ]). These does not seem to be probabilities.

Comment: I fitted a softmax function to these output values and now I get the probability values as array([  2.96420407e-003,   2.70332812e-002,   9.70002515e-001, 1.89663519e-020,   2.79800490e-118,   1.08216921e-172]) and this is the same as the output from predict_proba function in logistic regression (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict_proba).

Comment: After some research, I understand that here actually log(p(y=c)/1 - p(y=c)) is calculated. Hence, the 6 equations.